# What does handle_data() return?

Tags: python

I tried to get a list of only meaningful context from a webpage (there are only two lines of webpage content in my test code) using handle_data() from html.parser, but got multiple lists which are not in a list. I don't understand what does handle_data() returns. Anybody can help me with it? How can I store them in only one list?

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_data(self, data):
        a = []
        for i in data.split():
            a.append(i)
        print(a)
        return a

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

Result:
    ['Test']
    ['Parse', 'me!']

[image: results]

Comment: edit question, select code and use button `{}` on toolbar to correctly format code.

Comment: put HTML in question, not in comment.

Comment: you have to use button `{}` to format code - it adds 4 spaces before every line.

Comment: Correctly, thanks.

Comment: I would rather use `BeautifulSoup` and its `.get_text()`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that, but still curious about this funtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `handle_data` method from HTMLparser is called every time the parser found a text/content inside html tag.

In your case, `handle_data` will be called two times. In the first call, the variable `data` is equal to 'Test', and the second call will be 'Parse me!'.

If you want to store all of the text/content inside one list, then just create a variable inside your class.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    a = []

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.a.append(data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')

print(parser.a) # ['Test', 'Parse me!']
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know `http.parser` is low level module which can help to parse HTML but it returns nothing. You have to decide what to do with data. You can print it or put in some variable or create tree, etc. But this need to write all code which will return anything.

For example I create class variable `result` to keep all strings which I get in `handle_data` and later I can get all text from this variable.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    result = []

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.result.append(data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
print(parser.result)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. This answer is the same as the first one. I guess I only can choose one answer.